# controlling the number of columns in the exported tex file using -esttab-

Tags: latex, stata

I am trying to export a table of summary statistics in Latex, but when I compile the pdf with the table, the number of columns is not equal to the number of summary statistics (+1 for the first column relative to the variables).

As an example, consider this:

```
use auto, clear

eststo: estpost tabstat weight price mpg rep78, ///
    column(statistics) statistics(count mean median sd)

esttab using "auto.tex", replace ///
    cells(( count(label("Observations")) ///
    mean(label("Mean")) p50(label("Median")) ///
    sd(label("Standard deviation")) ))
```

If I manually change `auto.tex` so that:
`\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{ccccc}}` and not `\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}`, then the table is displayed correctly.

Which option am I missing here? Alternatively, is there a way to directly specify the number of columns?

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't a matter of choosing correct options. The final table is correctly shown if the content of `cell()` is a character, so that the following code works:

```
clear all
use auto, clear

eststo: estpost tabstat weight price mpg rep78, ///
    column(statistics) statistics(count mean median sd)

esttab using "C:\Users\Stefano\desktop\esttab tex\auto.tex", replace  ///
    cells( "count(label(Observations)) mean(label(Mean)) p50(label(Median)) sd(label(Standarddeviation))" ) ///
    booktabs noobs nomtitles nonum
```

Mind that Stata does not return error if the quotes are not used (as in the initial code). See the @Roberto answer and more in general the documentation for the reason for this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer given by @Stezzo:

Whether quotes are used or not, affects the way `esttab` presents results. Without the quotes, stacked results are presented. With the quotes, a side-by-side presentation is given. An example below.

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto

quietly regress price weight

esttab, cells(b t)
esttab, cells("b t")
```

Therefore, no error should be expected. This is intended behavior.

Recall that `esttab` is a wrapper for `estout`, and the former can take options from the latter. `cells()` is an option documented in `help estout`. The documentation explains the two arrangements.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @Roberto. It's still a bit weird in my opinion that the "stacked vs side-by-side" output is not controlled by an explicit option, but you're right: the documentation clarify this command behavior.

Comment: @Stezzo I don't know what the author of `estout` had in mind, but consider you can combine arrangements in one call. For example, `esttab, cells("b t" var)`. Doing this by way of explicit options would probably be a bit more painful.